# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource Error

Tags: php, reference

I have started learning php recently and have confront with this error while working on localhost. I have tried all possible solutions available on the web but haven't got ridden of the problem.
I am using VS code for text editing and installed php and apache(as the webserver) on windows 10. I have trying the code to get the input and print that on the screen but this error is showing every time.
Please help me out about this
I am including the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FORM</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--#an example showing the working of request variable-->
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_server['php_self'];?>">
        name:- <input type="text" name="fname" id="1">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form> 
    <?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
    {
        $name = $_REQUEST['fname'];
        if(empty($name))
        {
            echo "name is empty";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "NAME IS ";
            echo $name;
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), please edit and add the relevant code snippets to the question. Where are you stuck exactly, what have you done to debug your problem? Read [ask].

Comment: I have rectified the mistake you mentioned now if you can help that will be so generous of you

Comment: One thing noted, everything here should be uppercase: `$_server['php_self']`

Comment: Should I go with lowercase.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.